# C++ what is wrong with this do while loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to input a string. It's working fine when I input something like `John`.

But if I input something like `John Smite` I end up in an endless loop and a terminal crash.

```
string fullname;

do{
    cout << "Please input the Full Name of the user: ";
    cin >> fullname;
}while(fullname=="");
```

Comment: sorry its not a for loop, typo

Comment: Please provide an example that we can take, compile, and see what is happening for ourselves. Adding the appropriate headers to your code snippet does not result in anything that crashes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is throwing cin off. You should use getline.

Comment: No, it is not the space. Try it yourself. The code snippet as given (assuming appropriate includes etc.) is working fine for input like "John Smite"( where "fine" means, it does not crash, it will of course not put all words into the fullname variable).

Comment: Shouldn't "John Smite" produce the same result as "John" because std::cin tokenizes on the whitespace?

Comment: @Derek: for the contents of the fullname variable, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
do{
cout << "Please input the Full Name of the user: ";
cin >> fullname;
}
while(fullname.length() == 0);
```

Comment: in fact you dont even need a while loop because cin waits until a proper value is entered. but maybe you can use a while loop if you will check fullname is sth special.

Comment: @MihribanMNAZ: that depends on what you mean by "proper". If by proper, you mean a non-empty line, then no. cin will leave fullname empty when the user just hits enter, and I guess that the OP will just prevent that, by requiring a non-empty name.

Comment: The return value of string::length is of type `size_t`, so your condition would make more sense as `(fullname.length() == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

As to why you get an infinite loop - `operator>>` overload for `std::string` will first discard any leading whitespace and then read up to either next whitespace or the end of avaliable input.

When you enter "John Smite", first iteration reads "John", second iteration reads "Smite" and then there's no more input for subsequent iterations. The problem is that your implementation seems to clear `fullname` before it attempts a read. But because the stream is not in good state anymore, no more reads are possible and there's your infinite loop.

You could do something like this instead:

```
string temp;
string fullname;
do {
    cin.clear(); // clear any error flags
    do {
        if (cin >> temp) fullname += temp + ' ';
    } while (cin.good());
} while (fullname.empty());
```

This has a (good) side effect that it collapses multiple adjacent whitespace characters, but it's still pretty clunky.

Much better way would be to just say

```
do std::getline(std::cin, fullname); while (fullname.empty());
```